# Replacing/refactoring of naked pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want to replace traditional naked pointer usage in a class inheritance situation.

Example for what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
  void doBaseStuff ()
  {
    cout << "base stuff\n";
  }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
  void doDerivedStuff ()
  {
    cout << "derived stuff\n";
  }
};


int main ()
{
 // vector to hold pointers
  vector < Base * >baseCollection;

// generate pointers
  Derived *derivedPtr = new Derived;
  Base* basePtr = new Base;
  
 // use derived pointer for something
  derivedPtr->doDerivedStuff ();
  
 // fill vector with pointers
  baseCollection.push_back (basePtr);
  baseCollection.push_back (derivedPtr);

 // iterate some 'interface' method
 for (auto & element:baseCollection)
 {
   element->doBaseStuff ();
 }

  return 0;
}
```

Is refactoring this as shown below the correct way? I use C++17. `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr` won't compile in this case (line: `baseCollection.push_back(derivedPtr);`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// sample classes
class Base
{
public:
  void doBaseStuff ()
  {
    cout << "base stuff\n";
  }
};

class Derived:public Base
{
public:
  void doDerivedStuff ()
  {
    cout << "derived stuff\n";
  }
};


int main ()
{
 // vector to hold pointers
 vector<shared_ptr<Base>> baseCollection;
 
 // generate pointers
 shared_ptr<Base> basePtr = make_shared<Base>();
 shared_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = make_shared<Derived>();
 
 // use derived pointer for something
 derivedPtr->doDerivedStuff();
 
 // fill vector with pointers
 baseCollection.push_back(basePtr);
 baseCollection.push_back(derivedPtr); // implicit cast from shared_ptr<Derived> to shared_ptr<Base> !?
 
 // iterate some 'interface' method
 for(auto& element : baseCollection)
 {
     element->doBaseStuff();
 }

  return 0;
}
```

The output is the following in both cases, as expected:

```
derived stuff
base stuff
base stuff
```

Comment: `baseCollection.push_back( std::move(derivedPtr) );` would allow `derivedPtr` to be a `std::unique_ptr`.  [opinion warning] `std::shared_ptr` tends to be slower and tends to make code harder to reason with.  `std::unique_ptr` should be your first choice when it can be used.

Comment: @DrewDormann as I understand, unique_ptr prevents itself from being copied, so that it is guaranteed that to "forgotten" pointers to the same object exist...

Comment: *so that it is guaranteed that to "forgotten" pointers to the same object exist* I'm not sure what you mean here.  Use unique_ptr for ownership, use naked pointers for non-owning.

Comment: @Eljay The ownership concept _is_ actually what I meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr` (it is recommended indeed, because ownership is clearly handled in your application, and not left unspecified to a *kind-of* garbage-collector), but you have to **move** them into the vector in order to transfer (unique) ownership.

```
 vector<unique_ptr<Base>> baseCollection;
 
 // generate pointers
 unique_ptr<Base> basePtr = make_unique<Base>();
 unique_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = make_unique<Derived>();
 
 // use derived pointer for something
 derivedPtr->doDerivedStuff();
 
 // fill vector with pointers
 baseCollection.push_back(std::move(basePtr));
 baseCollection.push_back(std::move(derivedPtr));
```

Of course, you must not use your `basePtr` and `derivedPtr` variables afterwards because they don't own these objects anymore.

An alternative would be to use temporaries:

```
 baseCollection.push_back(make_unique<Base>());
 baseCollection.push_back(make_unique<Derived>());
```

Note that when dealing with `unique_ptr`s you can still use the raw pointers (with the `.get()` member-function) but the meaning is different: I **know** an object which is **owned** by someone else (a `unique_ptr` here).

And as stated in the comments, in order to ensure a correct destruction, the destructor of `Base` should be `virtual ~Base()=default;` because the destructor of `baseCollection` does not know that the `Base` pointer actually points to a `Derived` (probably not the same size, dynamic dispatch is needed). This is not related to `unique_ptr` nor `shared_ptr`; the problem existed with raw-pointers.
And to go further, since we have polymorphic types we should disable (`=delete`) copy/move-constructors/assign in order to prevent slicing, but we are far from the original question.

Comment: The behaviour of this program is undefined because it deletes an object of type `Derived` through a pointer of type `Base*`.

Comment: Ah, so the point is, that only one pointer exists (in this case in the std::vector)? I see! So unique_ptr / std::move is generally best practice for this scenario?

Comment: @VinzentMeier `unique_ptr` communicates "this pointer _owns_ the data pointed to." `shared_ptr` communicates "It is unclear or difficult to determine ownership of the data"

Answer (score 2):

> Is refactoring this as shown below the correct way?

The behaviour of the refactored program is different from the first. The first program leaks memory, while the refactored one does not. That's of course typically a good thing as long as it is intentional.

> I use C++17. std::unique_ptr instead of std::shared_ptr won't compile in this case.

That's because you make a copy of the pointer, and unique pointer aren't copyable. You can move the pointer instead. However, unique pointers to base have another problem that shared pointers don't have: If you delete a derived object through a pointer to base, and the destructor of base isn't virtual, then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. This can be easily fixed by making the destructor of the base virtual.

So, as long as you don't copy the pointer, and you make the destructor virtual, there would be no need to pay for the overhead of shared ownership.